# Can't save image to file properly with cimg library

Tags: c++, cimg

Here is the entirety of my code:

```
#include "CImg.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cimg_library;
int main() {

CImg<float> image(100,100,1,3,0);
const float color[] = {1.0,1.0,0.0};
image.draw_point(50,50,color);
image.save("file.bmp");
CImgDisplay local(image, "Hah");
while (true) {
    local.wait();
    }   

}
```

This successfully displays what I expect in a window, namely, a completely black square
with a white pixel at 50,50. However, file.bmp is simply a black square, without that
pixel (and saving a cimg Image that has been modified with repeated calls to draw_point
in a larger program that does something useful also fails). What's going on here?

Comment: +1 for a short, complete sample program. See http://sscce.org/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you create `CImgDisplay` with normalization enabled. Thus, your pixel of `{1,1,0}` is normalized to `{255,255,0}` and is visible on your screen.

`CImg.save` does not perform normalization, so the the pixel is saved to disk as a very dark pixel.

You can fix the problem by changing your white pixel color:

```
const float color[] = {255.,255.,255.};
```

And, optionally, by disabling normalization:

```
CImgDisplay local(image, "Hah", 0);
```

In the alternative, you could normalize the original image before saving or displaying it:

```
image.draw_point(50,50,color);
image.normalize(0, 255);
image.save("file.bmp");
```

References:

- [`CImgDisplay::CImgDisplay`](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/reference/structcimg__library_1_1CImgDisplay.html#a17a3e5d3c1452bea980a3fc27b94a62c)
- [`CImgDisplay::normalization`](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/reference/structcimg__library_1_1CImgDisplay.html#a67719cb05110ca9e5725bc59f8350b68)
- [`CImg::normalize`](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/reference/structcimg__library_1_1CImg.html#ab7943be99d0d4cfc6550d70039ecbf24)

Comment: This was exactly it, wasn't normalizing properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with this library but this behavior would allude that `CImgDisplay` is interpreting the image differently when rendering.

I would expect the color white to be defined as `const unsigned char color[] = {255,255,255};` to represent RGB values for the bitmap.

I would check the documentation for `CImg` as a first step.